# C# Source Generators Don't Play Nice With Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, sourcegenerators

So I've got this source generator in my ASP.NET Core MVC project that generates a view model like so:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using System.Text;

namespace SourceGenerator
{
    [Generator]
    public partial class ModelListGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new CustomSyntaxReceiver());
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            if (!(context.SyntaxReceiver is CustomSyntaxReceiver syntaxReceiver)) return;

            foreach (var classDeclarationSyntax in syntaxReceiver.ClassDeclarationSyntaxes)
            {
                //var className = classDeclarationSyntax.Identifier.Text;
            }

            string projectName = "Boilerplate";
            string className = "Person";
            string code = @$"

using {projectName}.Domain;
using {projectName}.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace {projectName}.Areas.AdminPortal.Models
{{
    public class {className}ListModel
    {{
        public {className}ListModel()
        {{
        }}

        public {className}ListModel(List<{className}> {className.ToLower()}s)
        {{

            foreach (var {className.ToLower()} in {className.ToLower()}s)
            {{
                {className}s.Add(new {className}Model({className.ToLower()}));
            }}
        }}

        public List<{className}Model> {className}s {{ get; set; }} = new List<{className}Model>();
    }}
}}

";
            context.AddSource("ModelList.cs", SourceText.From(code, Encoding.UTF8));
        }
    }
}
```

The source generator works splendidly.  However, when I try to load a view that makes use of the generated model, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Boilerplate.Areas.AdminPortal.Models.PersonListModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Boilerplate.Areas.AdminPortal.Models.PersonListModel'.

In other words, it's saying "I want a PersonListModel but you're giving me a PersonListModel" (LOL). If I then change `Boilerplate.Areas.AdminPortal.Models.PersonListModel` to simply `PersonListModel` while the app is running in debug mode, this fixes it temporarily.  But at some point, it will again display this error.  Then if I change the code from `PersonListModel` back to `Boilerplate.Areas.AdminPortal.Models.PersonListModel` (the original code), it again works for a while.

Clearly there's some kind of disconnect to where the Razor view engine is struggling to recognize that the model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is the correct one.  Is this a known bug?  Is there a workaround or am I simply out of luck?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an automatic version update add-in? If the assembly version changes between builds, you might get this kind of problem. Disable it and update the version manually or try rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @OlivierJacot-Descombes.  Sorry for the delay - I'm not on here too often and just work on the source generator occasionally as a side project.  I'm not using an automatic versioning system.

Comment: Note that two types having exactly the same name (including the namespace) declared in two projects are not considered to be the same type (because the assembly name and guid are considered to be part of the identity). You might have to add a third project as a class library (*.dll) declaring this type and reference it in the two other projects.